# Getting library values in Reusable workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, reusable

I have a custom doc library with columns "Dept Number" and "Dept Name"

I am creating a reusable workflow in which I wish to send an email to a user containing the above columns. Please tell me how to retrieve those columns and display them in my present email.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio to develop your workflow?

Comment: Hello Joy, I am using SharePoint Designer to create reusable workflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the Content Type of Document Library while creating Reusable wf.
2. To get access to your custom column, press the image button(Associate Columns) on the ribbon:
3. Press ‘Select Site Column’ and scroll until you find your column created in Step One.  Select it and press Ok (twice) to get back to the workflow design area.  (Below is image of SharePoint designer 2013)

[image]

After that you will get back to Workflow design where you can able to use it those columns in mail action/any other.

more information on it 
http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2011/10/28/why-i-love-reusable-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Workflow Variables. There is a category called Current Item and then you need to select your library field from that.

Comment: Hello Joy, I tried doing that. Its not retrieving the information. If you are creating workflows on a list/library then using "Current Item" option will work. I need to get information on a REUSABLE workflow

Comment: Oh, got it. Did you try using Associated Column option?